# Read system call on text files

Tags: linux, operating-system, text-files, system-calls

So I have the code below that i received to an examination and these two parts didn't really knew how to solve them.

```
#define MAX_LINE 4096
char line[MAX_LINE];

fd = open("../.././test.txt". O_RDONLY);
read(fd, line, MAX_LINE);
read(fd, line, MAX_LINE);
```

1. Explain which is the minimum and the maximum number of text lines that could be read by the given code.
2. Change the code to read exactly on line of text.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Explain which is the minimum and the maximum number of text lines that could be read by the given code.

Minimum is 0, or a fraction. Maximum is probably 2047 or 2048 if the line terminator is assumed to be `\n` alone, or 4096/3 +/- 1 if it is `\r\n`, or 4096 if the lines are allowed to be empty *and* the line terminator is assumed to be `\n`. I would say the question is radically underspecified, and complain.

> Change the code to read exactly on line of text.

Again this is radically underspecified. If use of `stdio` is allowed, which isn't stated, and aren't system calls, there are several choices. If it isn't, you would have to write a loop and a string-concatenation.

Comment: I have found out in the meantime the answer to the first part. Minimum is indeed 0. in this case the end of line is as you said \n. The maximum is 4096 * 2

Comment: The maximum is not 4096*2. That would imply that 8192 newline characters can fit into 4096 bytes. It is not possible.

Comment: Well yes, but the reads are destructive of what's in the buffer, so after the reads there can only be 4096 newlines in the buffer. Rather a poorly worded question, and somewhat pointless too, not to mention that newlines are not always a single byte, depending on the platform, and as this isn't specified the question is not answerable in principle. And nobody actually reads lines this way.

Answer (score -1):

I think fgets() is appropriate to read one line.

```
#define MAX_LINE 4096
char line[MAX_LINE];

FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("../.././test.txt", "r");
fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp); // read one line
```

Comment: The final argument to `fgets()` is not an FD. This will not compile or execute.

Comment: There are still compilation errors here, and you have still only answered half the question at best.